# disable auto rotate

Tags: ios, uiinterfaceorientation, autorotate

I have one specific viewcontroller which I wish to behave that way:
When loading, if device is landscaped, show landscape but no auto rotation.
When loading, if device is Portrait, show portrait but no auto rotation.
I cannot find the right solution for that, can any one advise?

Comment: have a look at here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the orietation on **viewWillAppear()** and then set views to show on the way you want according to the orientetation.

```
int orientationType = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
```

1 = Portrait 2 = Portrait (**Upside down**) 3 = landscape (**Right**) 4 = landscape (**Left**)

To **disable** auto rotate on a view just:

```
 - (BOOL) shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
 }
```

Comment: What's happening? Can you tell me more details?

Comment: I had to create a uinavigationviewcontroller with the code you mentioned above so the app would not auto rotate. But it's not what I initially wanted, I wanted that if the app is loaded when on landscape mode, so it will show on landscape and the same with the protrait, and at the same time, will not auto rotate if the user change the orientation